# What can be the reason that chrome is not opening after running simple code?

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, google-chrome, driver

I want to run an automation code on Chrome,
i download chrome driver and opened test project in C#
but after building and compiling the simple code bellow the chrome is not opened and just the cmd.
Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please download latest chromedriver

```
ChromeDriver 94.0.4606.61
```

from [here](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/). Also make sure that your chrome browser is up-to dated.

Also, I would suggest to use

```
driver.Get("website URL here");
```

instead of Navigate method.